# What is proper syntax to overload cast operator to std::map?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, typecast-operator

This is a C++03 question.

In the code below, `class Foo` is a template class that contains a map from a `std::string` to a `T` member function. `class Bar` contains a member variable of type `Foo<Bar>`. I would like to implement a cast-to-map operator in `class Foo` so that it is "pass-through" and can be used as though it were the *contained* map, without an explicit getter, but I can't quite work out the correct syntax for the cast operator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

#define FOO 1

template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
#if FOO
  operator
  std::map< std::string, void (T::*)( const std::string&,
                                      const std::string& ) >&()
  {
    return member_;
  }
#else
  Foo() : member_( 42 ) {}
  operator int&() { return member_; }
#endif

private:
#if FOO
  std::map< std::string, void (T::*)( const std::string&,
                                      const std::string& ) > member_;
#else
  int member_;
#endif
};

class Bar
{
public:
#if FOO
  void func()
  {
    fb_["a"] = &Bar::abc;
  }
#else
  void func()
  {
    std::cout << fb_ << std::endl;
  }
#endif

  void abc( const std::string& key, const std::string& val )
  {
    std::cout << key << ": " << val << std::endl;
  }

private:
  Foo<Bar> fb_;
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  Bar b;
  b.func();
  return 0;
}
```

The compile error is cryptic; I don't know what to make of it:

```
>g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

>g++ -g main.cpp 
main.cpp: In member function 'void Bar::func()':
main.cpp:33:8: error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Foo<Bar>' and 'const char [2]')
     fb_["a"] = &Bar::abc;
```

You can see I've toyed with a cast-to-int operator, which works fine, but its syntax is perhaps overly simple for me to extrapolate to a cast-to-map operator.

Can someone help with the correct syntax please?

Comment: `typedef` is your friend.  That said, there's still a question of whether implicit conversions are performed on the target object of a subscript operator.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Well, I just tried `typedef std::map< std::string, void (T::*)( const std::string&, const std::string& ) > FooMap;`, which helps a bit with readability. But that just gives me `operator FooMap&() { ... }` with the same compile error. Was there something else you were suggesting that I missed?

Comment: No, that's all I meant by suggesting `typedef`.  The reason your code won't compile is that a subscript operator `x[y]` is transformed to `x.operator[](y)` and conversions are possible on the parameter but not on the target object.  What you want just isn't possible, you need a forwarding function.

Comment: @BenVoigt Is there further reading on what you're describing? (Or maybe you can post an answer? It's maybe hard to capture details in the limits of this comment section?) I'm probably not understanding your answer very well, because I still fail to see why the cast-to-int operator works when the cast-to-map does not. Something to with the involvement of the subscript operator...? I'm not quite seeing the full picture.

Comment: I'm looking for an existing clear explanation so I don't have to write it ;)   BTW does your code compile with FOO undefined and `std::cout << fb_["abc"];` ?  That's legal with an actual `int` (well, a value of 42 will break at runtime because the string literal isn't long enough).

Comment: @BenVoigt Sorry for delayed response; had to step away. My code does compile and run with FOO undefined and `std::cout << fb_["abc"]`, and outputs garbage, as might be expected.

Answer (score 1):

@BenVoight guided me to this realization: the `operator[]` function call gets applied on the "original" object, not the "passed-through" object. I.e. even though I've implemented a typecast-to-map operator in `class Foo`, the `operator[]` I subsequently call still gets applied to the `Foo` object and not to the `std::map` to which my `Foo` object is typecast.

This gave me the idea that perhaps what I needed was to overload `operator[]`, which I did to apparent success:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
  typedef void (T::*TFunc)( const std::string&, const std::string& );
  typedef std::map< std::string, TFunc > FooMap;
  operator FooMap&()
  {
    return member_;
  }

  TFunc& operator []( const std::string& str )
  {
    return member_[ str ];
  }

private:
  FooMap member_;
};

class Bar
{
public:
  void func()
  {
    fb_["a"] = &Bar::abc;
  }

  void callFunc( const std::string& str, const std::string arg1,
                 const std::string& arg2 )
  {
    (this->*fb_[ str ])( arg1, arg2 );
  }

  void abc( const std::string& key, const std::string& val )
  {
    std::cout << key << ": " << val << std::endl;
  }

private:
  Foo<Bar> fb_;
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  Bar b;
  b.func();
  b.callFunc( "a", "hello", "world" );
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
>g++ -g main.cpp 
>./a.out    
hello: world
```

Comment: Yup, that's it.  At first I interpreted your "don't want a getter function" as meaning you knew about the possible forwarding `operator[]` but on second thought I guess you were meaning `_fb[x]` vs `_fb.get()[x]`